# Amazon EC2 - How to execute the 'launch" part of a Cross-Account AMI Copy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**Context**

I would like to perform a Cross-Account AMI Copy (I'm really trying to do this in C#, using the Amazon SDK, but need to understand it from a EC2 Console perspective, as well).  The purpose is to back up an instance and it's volumes in one account (the first AMI) and then make a copy of this AMI in another account (so now two distinct AMI's, in two different S3 storage areas).

Currently, my code does the following:

1. Finds the Instance to create an Image for (based on User Input).
2. Creates an Image (AMI) of this Instance.
3. After the Image Completes successfully, I share the AMI to another Account (Using LaunchPermissions on the Image. At this moment, it is not clear to me if I need to also share the Volumes using CreateVolumePermission).

There, I want to perform a Copy. The problem is that when I try to copy it I get this message:

> Images with EC2 BillingProduct codes cannot be copied to another AWS account.

But, I did some reading and it said I could do the following:

Launch an EC2 instance of this shared Image and then create an AMI from this instance. Great!

**Here is my issue**

Just now, through the console (website), I am logged into the 2nd account, I selected the shared image and clicked the big Launch button.

Next, it took me to a screen where it wants me to choose an instance type (it is defaulted to t2.micro). In addition, there are other steps like "Configure Instance", "Add Storage", "Configure Security Group", etc.

For my purposes I just want to back up an Instance and it's volumes (using AMI to do this).  Instead of defaulting to things like t2.micro, shouldn't all my configuration steps just match the Instance I took the image from (albeit I just have the AMI that is shared to this 2nd account, and can't really see the original instance, just the AMI that is shared to it)?

When I look at the original instance (from the first account), I see t2.medium, and I see security groups such as: RDP(3389)-HTTP(80)-HTTPS(443)-SSH(22)

In other words, I just want my "Launch" to take on the properties of the Instance I took an AMI of. Shouldn't it default to these properties? Or, how can I default it to these properties?

More context: After I'm done with this Launch, where the purpose is to create an AMI of it (or "the copy"), I would think that I no longer need the Instance and can delete it. I'm only launching just to create "the copy".

Comment: What type of original disk is it? Did it come from Marketplace? That would explain the "EC2 BillingProduct codes" message.

Comment: I'm actually not sure.  I've been sort of thrust into all this: "here programmer, do some amazon things ... go!".  So as little as two weeks ago, I knew nothing, including what "EC2" was.   That being said, these instances are something we create for customers to host our web-based application.  I'm not sure if it would come from the marketplace, or if it's from some image we created that was "Windows O/S 10, updated to this date, with our app on it, updated to the latest version".

Answer (score 2):

An AMI is separate to an Instance. The AMI merely has a **copy of the disk volumes** that were associated within an instance. None of the other properties about the instance are kept with an AMI.

Within your own account and region, you can use **Launch More Like This** in the EC2 management console, which will copy attributes like instance type, tags, user data, etc to a new instasnce. This is a feature of the console and is *not* mirrored by actual API calls in AWS.

Security Groups are totally separate objects. An instance can be associated with multiple security groups, but the security groups are not copied as part of an instance.

**Bottom line:** There is no API call to "clone" an instance and all its properties. You will need to specify these properties during launch.

Here is the type of information kept about an AMI:

```
{
    "Images": [
        {
            "VirtualizationType": "paravirtual",
            "Name": "My server",
            "Hypervisor": "xen",
            "ImageId": "ami-5731123e",
            "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
            "State": "available",
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                    "Ebs": {
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "SnapshotId": "snap-1234567890abcdef0",
                        "VolumeSize": 8,
                        "VolumeType": "standard"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "ImageLocation": "123456789012/My server",
            "KernelId": "aki-88aa75e1",
            "OwnerId": "123456789012",
            "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
            "Public": false,
            "ImageType": "machine",
            "Description": "An AMI for my server"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just to take a step back, at first we had thought to just take snapshots on some interval.  This would allow us to backup the O/S, where it was update-wise, the application we install and it's data.  Creating an AMI, instead, seemed like a better idea as you still get the snapshots, but also some type of "metadata" (whatever that may be) of that instance.  We also want two copies, one in the customer acct, and one in some other account (hence the cross-account sharing).  Now I'm wondering what this metadata is if it's not going to get me info about the instance I originally imaged.

Comment: The _data_ in an AMI is kept in a snapshot. The different is that an AMI can contain _multiple snapshots_, together with sharing information. I've added details above. Also, an instance can be Launched from an AMI. It is not possible Launch directly from a snapshot.

Comment: Yes, being that an instance can be launched from an AMI, it seemed like that was the better route to go than just taking snapshots.  It now seems like to me, that maybe I shouldn't worry about if I'm using t2.micro to launch an instance, even though the original instance (that the ami was created from) might have been t2.medium.  Or that the original instance had a certain security group.  I'm just launching, so I can copy an AMI.  If I need this ami because the original instance fails, I can worry about those details then.  But for copy purposes, probably not.  Would you agree?

Comment: Basically, the jist is that I want to make backups of customer instances in case of failure.  It seemed that AMI's were the best way to do that.  But I'm not sure what best practices are since I'm just dipping my toes in the water.  ... And thanks so much for your time and input.

Comment: The "best practice" is to launch instances from a CloudFormation template, which defines all the attributes of the instance. Then, if another instance is required (even in a different region), the template can be used to launch another instance with exactly the same attributes. Admittedly, the disk will not contain a 'copy' of the data, but best practice is to store data off-instance, typically in a database or in Amazon S3.

Comment: I noticed that you are a  Senior Technical Trainer at Amazon Web Services.  Does Amazon offer on-site (as in the trainer comes to us) training?  We would personally be interested in training, tailored to exactly what we are doing, as opposed to a generic how-to that tries to cover all the bases.  Is this something that Amazon offers?

Comment: @JustLooking See: [AWS Classroom Training](https://www.aws.training/Training?searchPhrase=classroom)